# EntityExistsException при апдейте, но при сохранении всё ОК

Tags: spring, hibernate, update

У меня есть сущность-родитель(User) с 2 связными one-to-many сущностями(Apps,Docs). Когда я создаю новую, всё хорошо: создаётся родительская сущность и связные сущности (в БД). Но когда я делаю апдейт этих же сущностей (после модификации данных), выпадает ошибка "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session [model.App#124]" (Другой объект с таким же значением идентификатора уже связан с сессией).
С чем может быть связана проблема? Не смог найти подходящей информации через гугл (возможно, руки не оттуда).
Заранее спасибо!!!

Код:

```
Class User

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private List<App> apps;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Doc> docs;

Class App

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private User user;

Controller
Save
    for(int i=0;i<user.getDocs().size();i++) {
        user.getDocs().get(i).setUser(user);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<user.getApps().size();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<user.getApps().get(i).getMarks().size();j++) {
            user.getApps().get(i).getMarks().get(j).setApp(user.getApps().get(i));
        }
        user.getApps().get(i).setUser(user);
        user.getApps().get(i).setCreate_date();
    }
    userService.saveUser(user);

Update
for(int i=0;i<user.getDocs().size();i++) {
        user.getDocs().get(i).setUser(user);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<user.getApps().size();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<user.getApps().get(i).getMarks().size();j++) {
           user.getApps().get(i).getMarks().get(j).setApp(user.getApps().get(i));
        }
        user.getApps().get(i).setUser(user);
        user.getApps().get(i).setUpdate_date();
    }
    userService.updateUser(user);
```

Comment: Please, ask questions in Russian

Comment: Поправил, спасибо за подсказку!